# child object in an embedded component

Tags: event-system, schema, dynamic-linking

I have converted some code from VB6 to VB.NET, using the default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> where necessary.

I now get an error on the line:

```
For Each objChild In objItem.value(iSub)
```

saying that

> Expression is of type 'Object', which is not a collection type.

Does any one have the correct conversion please?

Original VB code

```
Private Function ValidateAnItem(ByRef objItem As TDS.ItemField) As String
For iSub = 1 To objItem.Value.Count
  If objItem.FieldType = FieldTypeEmbed Then
      For Each objChild In objItem.Value(iSub)
          strReturn = ValidateAnItem(objChild, strAdministrator)
          If strReturn <> "" Then
             ValidateAnItem = strReturn
             Set objChild = Nothing
             Exit For
            Exit Function
         End If
     Next
 End If
```

Next

code converted to vb.net

```
Public Function ValidateAnItem(ByRef objItem As TDS.ItemField) As String
    Dim objChild As TDS.ItemField
    For iSub = 1 To objItem.value.Count
         If objItem.FieldType = TDSDefines.EnumTridionWebSchemaFieldType.FieldTypeEmbed Then
               For Each objChild In objItem.value(iSub)
                     strReturn = ValidateAnItem(objChild)
                     If strReturn <> "" Then
                         ValidateAnItem = strReturn
                         objChild = Nothing
                         Exit For
                         Exit Function
                      End If

[...]
```

Comment: It might help the community to answer if you show what you've tried doing to fix this and explain the context of what this code is doing. "Please fix my code" type questions don't generally get good responses. What is this code for? What does the Schema/Page/Component Template consist of? Also please specify the version of Tridion you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The line "For Each objChild In objItem.value(iSub)" refers the value of a field.

I guess VB.Net is thrown off by the fact that the 'Value' can refer to non collection types (like strings) as well as collection types (like ItemFields).

The solution depends on what you're trying to iterate over. If you want to iterate over all the values of a field called objItem, do this:

```
For Each objChild In objItem.value*
```

If you want to iterate over the fields embedded inside an embeddable field, do this:

```
Dim objEmbeddedFields As TDS.ItemFields
Set objEmbeddedFields = objItem.value(iSub)
For Each objChild As TDS.ItemField In objEmbeddedFields*
```

**Untested code disclaimer.*

Comment: Thank you everyone, i have removed the brakets on the line For Each objChild In objItem.value, it at least compiles now, i am trying to validate a URL on a component link field within the event system, onComponentSavePre, the version of Tridion is r2009, and the vb.net / visual studio is 2008 sp1

Comment: If this answer solved the problem, could you mark it as correct please?

Comment: This answer has solved my problem

Comment: The idea is that you mark the answer as 'correct' by clicking on the 'checkmark' icon to the left of the answer.

Comment: +1 to clicking the check box in StackExchange to accept this answer. It's good for future askers, good for the community, and also good for Quirijn. :-)